# 80's teen novel about survivors fighting an alien invasion of earth

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to find a sci-fi story I read in the mid 80's which I think was for roughly the 10-15 age range.  Things I can remember:

- I think the protagonist was a teenage boy. He might have had a dog.
- There had been an alien invasion which had destroyed most of society, with only small groups of survivors trying to fight back
- The aliens used drones such as flying robotic birds with flame throwers that hovered in the sky and hunted for survivors.
- Set in the UK possibly, but I might be conflating that with John Christopher's *Tripods* books which had a similar feel and that I read about the same time.
- They captured one of the 'birds' at one point and discovered it was full of a red gelatinous substance : some kind of alien technology for controlling the machines
- I think no-one had seen the aliens, which were a mystery (at least at the start of the book), but that might also be conflation with the Tripods.

Not a whole lot to go on I'm afraid.

Comment: Not certain enough to post as an answer, but The Huntsman by Douglas Hill (best known for the Last Legionary books) matches some points and fits with the timeline.

Comment: If it is _The Huntsman_ the "birds" are called _spywings_. The protagonist _Finn_ does catch one but is full of mechanisms and a green fluid not a red gelatinous substance. The _spywings_ don't have flame throwers but the aliens (the _Slavers_) do use _heatlances_. If this ring a bell with you then maybe @Kerr could post it as an answer.

Comment: If so then it is a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/251903/story-identification-childrens-sci-fi-circa-1980s I'll have a look later to see if I can dig out my copy for a good answer to this question.

Comment: The  name of the book doesn't sound familiar,  but "spywings" as the name for the birds does.  Looking up what details I can find rings a few more bells. Can't be certain, but there's a good chance that's the right book, allowing for unreliable memory from 40 years ago. I'd accept it as an answer if nothing else is suggested that I recognise.