# Book series written 1980-2010s about a boy with supernatural hunting skills finds out he's an alien experiment

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

The book was written around the 1980's - 2010s. I believe it is the first book of a series. Can't seem to find it anywhere. Maybe banned for its science fiction or just no copies since it was last sold. Most likely made in the 1990s if the dates are right.

It starts with a boy (possibly a teenager) with supernaturally good hunting/tracking skills. One day he comes back from a hunt and finds out (or sees) his sister and father get kidnapped by aliens and are taken on their (called it) hovercraft. Tracks them but they split up into two groups, he decides to follow the left(?) group and finds animals along the way with funny tattoos.

Comes across a cave/facility by the aliens and meets an alien that is more human and alien with a human brain(so talks and acts like a human) and finds test tubes with baby humans in them. They are experiments by the aliens trying to infuse animal abilities with humans, and the test subjects all have a tattoo (a circle with a triangle) that is exactly like his birthmark.

Finds out he is an alien experiment human alien joins forces with him takes out the facility( which has never been done before) and finishes the book heading out to another facility where he has tracked his sister and father.

Comment: Is this a dystopia where science fiction books are banned? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[The Huntsman](https://www.amazon.com.au/Huntsman-Douglas-Hill/dp/0330269569) (1982) by Douglas Hill**

You have described the plot of the first book in the trilogy very well.  The world has been invaded by aliens (Slavers) many years ago and the surviving humans reduced to living in isolated villages with iron-age technology.  Finn is found as a child with a strange birthmark/tattoo and no memory of his past.  Joshua adopts Finn into his house, then Finn returns home one day to find Joshua and Jena (Joshua's natural daughter) taken by a Slaver raid.  He tracks them with his supernatural tracking skills, detecting the disturbance of the ground from the Slaver craft flying low above it.  Along the way he meets a bear-like man (possibly nicknamed Bear?) who is a defector from the Slavers group of genetically-altered human minions and they team up.

My recollection is that the final infiltration of the Slaver camp lets Finn see babies with the same markings that he has, at which point he realises that he is also one of their experiments.  Bear(?) had realised this earlier when he saw Finns markings, but did not reveal it at that time and his bear-like hair concealed his own similar markings.  I thought that Joshua died during the conclusion of the first book, but that may be incorrect.  He is definitely continuing to look for Jena, which is the focus of the second book, *Warriors of the Wasteland*.  (I'll see if my daughter can find her copy of the book later, for now I'm relying on memory.)

While not as well known or memorable as Douglas Hill's *Last Legionary* series, the Huntsman trilogy certainly was not banned, it just fell into relative obscurity over the decades.

Note:  Just found that, if correct, this is a duplicate of [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/251903/story-identification-childrens-sci-fi-circa-1980s/251905#251905).